# Where do I check for invalid folder permissions when uploading file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to return a specific error message when trying to upload a file to a folder when the user does not have write permissions.

Currently, my code looks like:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile(string id)
{
    // ...some validation checking here...

    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        throw new HttpResponseException
        (
            new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(Strings.UnsupportedMediaType)
            }
        );


    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("/path/to/folder");
    var parts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    var fileData = parts.FileData.FirstOrDefault();

    //...other stuff...

    return Ok();
}
```

My question is: where would I do the check for if I don't have the right permissions to the folder?

In other words: would `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` raise an exception? Would `ReadAsMultipartAsync` raise an exception?  I know that there is a `UnauthorizedAccessException` but it doesn't seem like any of the functions I'm calling throws that exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation for [`ReadAsMultipartAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944544(v=vs.118).aspx) and [`MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider.multipartformdatastreamprovider(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider), neither of those appear to throw any exceptions

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/), It has lots of examples.

Comment: @RufusL yea that's what I discovered too.  So what happens when trying to write to a folder that you do not have permissions to?

Comment: I don't know; try it and find out...